# Que hace la funcion math.floor() JS

Tags: javascript

Alguien me puede explicar el siguiente codigo, especialmente la parte de la operacion con Math.floor() y por que se divide dif/(1000 * 24 * 60 * 60)

```js
var fecha1 = "12/06/2008";
var dia1 = fecha1.substr(0, 2);
var mes1 = fecha1.substr(3, 2);
var anyo1 = fecha1.substr(6);

var fecha2 = "29/06/2008";
var dia2 = fecha2.substr(0, 2);
var mes2 = fecha2.substr(3, 2);
var anyo2 = fecha2.substr(6);

var nuevafecha1 = new Date(anyo1 + "," + mes1 + "," + dia1);
var nuevafecha2 = new Date(anyo2 + "," + mes2 + "," + dia2);

var Dif = nuevafecha2.getTime() - nuevafecha1.getTime();
var dias = Math.floor(Dif / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60));
alert(dias);
```

Comment: `Math.floor` es un método de la librería `Math` de `Javascript` utilizado para redondear a la baja un número con decimales. Por ejemplo `Math.floor(1.6);` nos devolvería `1` ya que es el integer más cercano redondeando a la baja `1.6`

Comment: @JuankGlezz Era un apunte rápido para que ayudase al OP hasta el momento en el que redactase la explicación del código, pero veo que otro usuario ya lo ha explicado bastante bien más abajo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí mis dos centavos con una explicación rápida:

```
// definir variables
var fecha1 = "12/06/2008";

// tomar los dos primeros caracteres de fecha1
var dia1 = fecha1.substr(0, 2);

// a partir de la posicion 3 de fecha1 tomar los 2 siguientes caracteres
var mes1 = fecha1.substr(3, 2);

// tomar todos los caracteres de fecha1 a partir de la posición 6
var anyo1 = fecha1.substr(6);

// igual que las anteriores
var fecha2 = "29/06/2008";
var dia2 = fecha2.substr(0, 2);
var mes2 = fecha2.substr(3, 2);
var anyo2 = fecha2.substr(6);

// crear una instancia de Date (fecha) con los valores obtenidos arriba
var nuevafecha1 = new Date(anyo1 + "," + mes1 + "," + dia1);

// crear otra instancia de Date
var nuevafecha2 = new Date(anyo2 + "," + mes2 + "," + dia2);

// obtener el valor numérico que corresponde a cada una de las fechas
// y obtener la diferencia (resta) entre la segunda y la primera.
// Este valor está dado en milisegundos
var Dif = nuevafecha2.getTime() - nuevafecha1.getTime();

// dividir el valor obtenido arriba entre la constante equivalente a 1 día
// Redondear el resultado de la división al entero menor con la función Math.floor()
// de forma tal que si el resultado es 17.3432, se obtendrá 17
var dias = Math.floor(Dif / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60));

// mostrar una ventana emergente con el resultado final
alert(dias);
```

Entrando en detalle en el porqué se divide por 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60, viene del hecho que el valor que se obtiene de `getTime()` está dado en milisegundos, entonces para obtener el equivalente en días, es necesario armar el equivalente a un día:

> 1000 milisegundos = 1 segundo
>
> x 60 segundos = 1 minuto
>
> x 60 minutos = 1 hora
>
> x 24 horas = 1 día

Answer (score 1):

Optimicé un poco tu código y la repuesta del por que esta operación matemática es para sacar el día pero no veo necesario en este caso debido a que esta operación no va a cambiar, siempre va a ser la misma para obtener 1:

```js
function cambiarFormato(fecha){
 var fechaSplit = fecha.split('/')
 return new Date(fechaSplit[2],fechaSplit[1], fechaSplit[0])
}

var fecha1 = "12/06/2008"
var nuevafecha1 = cambiarFormato(fecha1);

var fecha2 = "29/06/2008";
var nuevafecha2 = cambiarFormato(fecha2)
var Dif = nuevafecha2.getTime() - nuevafecha1.getTime();
var dias = Math.floor(Dif / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60));
alert(dias);
```